# How does one target IE7 and IE8 with valid CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, web-standards

I want to target IE7 and IE8 with W3C-compliant CSS. Sometimes fixing CSS for one version does not fix for the other. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Scroll down to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20982264/1256925) for a full list of ways to apply styles to specific browsers only.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

**Explicitly Target IE versions without hacks using HTML and CSS**

Use this approach if you don't want hacks in your CSS. Add a browser-unique class to the `<html>` element so you can select based on browser later.

Example

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Then in your CSS you can very strictly access your target browser.

Example

```
.ie6 body { 
    border:1px solid red;
}
.ie7 body { 
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

For more information check out http://html5boilerplate.com/

**Target IE versions with CSS "Hacks"**

More to your point, here are the hacks that let you target IE versions.

Use "\9" to target IE8 and below.
Use "*" to target IE7 and below.
Use "_" to target IE6.

Example:

```
body { 
border:1px solid red; /* standard */
border:1px solid blue\9; /* IE8 and below */
*border:1px solid orange; /* IE7 and below */
_border:1px solid blue; /* IE6 */
}
```

**Update: Target IE10**

IE10 does not recognize the conditional statements so you can use this to apply an "ie10" class to the `<html>` element

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <!--[if !IE]><!--><script>if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';}</script><!--<![endif]-->
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cool. I'm copying this into my Evernote account for reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, on top of being invalid CSS, IE9 and IE10 will apply the `\9` declaration as well.

Comment: Are you not missing ie7 in first example?

Comment: Edited to include a condition for ie7

Comment: The other answer is much better, you don't want to include trash in your main css, it's better to have a bad.css for bad browsers.

Comment: @potench How can I target something like  "IF ! IE8" ?

Comment: @SaurabhBayani you don't want to do that. But basically !--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> would do it, unless you're shooting for ie 5/6/7 only .

Comment: Highly recommend you don't use CSS hacks to target elements for browsers. You don't know what browsers might support that in the future which could break your website.

Comment: IE9 won't apply `\9` without spaces between it and the value. But IE10 will apply.

Answer (score 21):

I would recommend looking into conditional comments and making a separate sheet for the IEs you are having problems with.

```
 <!--[if IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 9):

### The answer to your question

A completely valid way to select all browsers but IE8 and below is using the `:root` selector. Since IE versions 8 and below do not support `:root`, selectors containing it are ignored. This means you could do something like this:

```
p {color:red;}
:root p {color:blue;}
```

This is still completely valid CSS, but it does cause IE8 and lower to render different styles.

### Other tricks

Here's a list of all completely valid CSS browser-specific selectors I could find, *except* for some that seem quite redundant, such as ones that select for just 1 type of ancient browser ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_hack#body:empty_hack), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_hack#Commented_backslash)):

```
/******  First the hacks that target certain specific browsers  ******/
* html p                        {color:red;} /* IE 6- */
*+html p                        {color:red;} /* IE 7 only */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    p                           {color:red;}
}                                            /* Chrome, Safari 3+ */
p, body:-moz-any-link           {color:red;} /* Firefox 1+ */
:-webkit-any(html) p            {color:red;} /* Chrome 12+, Safari 5.1.3+ */
:-moz-any(html) p               {color:red;} /* Firefox 4+ */

/****** And then the hacks that target all but certain browsers ******/
html> body p                  {color:green;} /* not: IE<7 */
head~body p                   {color:green;} /* not: IE<7, Opera<9, Safari<3 */
html:first-child p            {color:green;} /* not: IE<7, Opera<9.5, Safari&Chrome<4, FF<3 */
html>/**/body p               {color:green;} /* not: IE<8 */
body:first-of-type p          {color:green;} /* not: IE<9, Opera<9, Safari<3, FF<3.5 */
:not([ie8min]) p              {color:green;} /* not: IE<9, Opera<9.5, Safari<3.2 */
body:not([oldbrowser]) p      {color:green;} /* not: IE<9, Opera<9.5, Safari<3.2 */
```

### Credits & sources:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_hack
- http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks
- MDN: [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child#Browser_compatibility);
  [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root#Browser_compatibility);
  [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type#Browser_compatibility);
  [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility);
  [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any#Browser_compatibility);
  [`* ~ *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 7):

For a more complete list as of 2015:

### IE 6

```
* html .ie6 {property:value;}
```

or

```
.ie6 { _property:value;}
```

### IE 7

```
*+html .ie7 {property:value;}
```

or

```
*:first-child+html .ie7 {property:value;}
```

### IE 6 and 7

```
@media screen\9 {
    .ie67 {property:value;}
}
```

or

```
.ie67 { *property:value;}
```

or

```
.ie67 { #property:value;}
```

### IE 6, 7 and 8

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 {
    .ie678 {property:value;}
}
```

### IE 8

```
html>/**/body .ie8 {property:value;}
```

or

```
@media \0screen {
    .ie8 {property:value;}
}
```

### IE 8 Standards Mode Only

```
.ie8 { property /*\**/: value\9 }
```

### IE 8,9 and 10

```
@media screen\0 {
    .ie8910 {property:value;}
}
```

### IE 9 only

```
@media screen and (min-width:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { 
 // IE9 CSS
 .ie9{property:value;}
}
```

### IE 9 and above

```
@media screen and (min-width:0) and (min-resolution: +72dpi) {
  // IE9+ CSS
  .ie9up{property:value;}
}
```

### IE 9 and 10

```
@media screen and (min-width:0) {
    .ie910{property:value;}
}
```

### IE 10 only

```
_:-ms-lang(x), .ie10 { property:value\9; }
```

### IE 10 and above

```
_:-ms-lang(x), .ie10up { property:value; }
```

or

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   .ie10up{property:value;}
}
```

### IE 11 (and above..)

```
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .ie11up { property:value; }
```

---

### Javascript alternatives

#### [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

> Modernizr runs quickly on page load to detect features; it then
>   creates a JavaScript object with the results, and adds classes to the
>   html element

#### [User agent selection](http://rog.ie/blog/html5-boilerplate-addon)

The Javascript:

```
var b = document.documentElement;
        b.setAttribute('data-useragent',  navigator.userAgent);
        b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
        b.className += ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window))?' touch':'');
```

Adds (e.g) the below to the `html` element:

```
data-useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)'
data-platform='Win32'
```

Allowing very targetted CSS selectors, e.g.:

```
html[data-useragent*='Chrome/13.0'] .nav{
    background:url(img/radial_grad.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

---

### Footnote

If possible, avoid browser targeting. Identify and fix any issue(s) you identify. Support [**progressive enhancement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [**graceful degradation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tolerance).  With that in mind, this is an 'ideal world' scenario not always obtainable in a production environment, as such- the above should help provide some good options.

---

#### Attribution / Essential Reading

- [Keith Clarke](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/)
- [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)
- [Web Devout](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks)
- [The Spanner](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2009/01/29/detecting-browsers-javascript-hacks/)

Answer (score 4):

Well you don't really have to worry about IE7 code not working in IE8 because IE8 has compatibility mode (it can render pages the same as IE7). But if you still want to target different versions of IE, a way that's been done for a while now is to either use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) or [begin your css rule with a * to target IE7 and below](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/63). Or you could pay attention to user agent on the servers and dish up a different CSS file based on that information.

Comment: Thanks.. but using * hack is Not valid W3C CSS . so it might be Problem. and Conditional comment is Useful solution. but It Create much larger version of HTML file.. so might be We create Diff CSS. like IE7.css , Is there any conditional comment for IE8.
Once again thansk Apphacker

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is not IE8, but the hacks that you use for earlier versions of IE.

IE8 is pretty close to be standards compliant, so you shouldn't need any hacks at all for it, perhaps only some tweaks. The problem is if you are using some hacks for IE6 and IE7; you will have to make sure that they only apply to those versions and not IE8.

I made the web site of our company compatible with IE8 a while ago. The only thing that I actually changed was adding the meta tag that tells IE that the pages are IE8 compliant...

Comment: Oh,, sounds Good.  Can you please let Us know.. what META tag.

Comment: The X-UA-Compatible meta tag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc817574.aspx

Comment: +1 Indeed, IE 8 has much less problems and one hasn't to "crossbrowserfiy" to much for it. And IE 9 Is fantastic and make a strong competition to Chrome.

Comment: IE8 is not standards compliant by a long shot. It can't handle border-radius or svg. It's a stone age browser.

Comment: @Morg.: You can't expect an old browser to comply to standards that were added after the browser was released. Even if it is ancient, you have to consider how many there is that still uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using Javascript. I add three css classes to the html element:

```
ie<version>
lte-ie<version>
lt-ie<version + 1>
```

So for IE7, it adds `ie7`, `lte-ie7` ..., `lt-ie8` ...

Here is the javascript code:

```
(function () {
    function getIEVersion() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
        var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

        if (msie > 0) {
            // IE 10 or older => return version number
            return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
        } else if (trident > 0) {
            // IE 11 (or newer) => return version number
            var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
            return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
        } else {
            return NaN;
        }
    };

    var ieVersion = getIEVersion();

    if (!isNaN(ieVersion)) { // if it is IE
        var minVersion = 6;
        var maxVersion = 13; // adjust this appropriately

        if (ieVersion >= minVersion && ieVersion <= maxVersion) {
            var htmlElem = document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0);

            var addHtmlClass = function (className) { // define function to add class to 'html' element
                htmlElem.className += ' ' + className;
            };

            addHtmlClass('ie' + ieVersion); // add current version
            addHtmlClass('lte-ie' + ieVersion);

            if (ieVersion < maxVersion) {
                for (var i = ieVersion + 1; i <= maxVersion; ++i) {
                    addHtmlClass('lte-ie' + i);
                    addHtmlClass('lt-ie' + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Thereafter, you use the `.ie<version>` css class in your stylesheet as described by potench.

(Used Mario's detectIE function in [Check if user is using IE with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie))

The benefit of having lte-ie8 and lt-ie8 etc is that it you can target all browser less than or equal to IE9, that is IE7 - IE9.