# IE8 div pushes down

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 the menu div main-navigation-wrapper pushes down into the blue slider image.

Does anyone know why that is? I tried adding this to the IE7 style sheet, but I'm assuming that only works for IE7?

```
div#main-superfish-wrapper{ margin-left: 0; padding:0;}
```

Edit: this is the site in question http://bit.ly/ZgawU6

Digging deeper into the problem, I found this link: [How does one target IE7 and IE8 with valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814219/how-does-one-target-ie7-and-ie8-with-valid-css)

The offending div seems to actually be main-navigation-wrapper (I think...)

So in theory if I add this to my main style.css file, it should work?

.ie ie8 main-navigation-wrapper{ margin-left: 0; padding:0; z-index:999;}

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Hmm, it's kind of hard to replicate or find the code for as it's only in IE8? I've only got access to IE8 on a demo from this site..  http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add z-index

> div#main-superfish-wrapper{ margin-left: 0; padding:0; `z-index:999;`}

into your css mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'm having trouble replicating it? Can anyone test on IE8?