# Extra pixel in firefox on dropdown hover and nav bar not working in IE 8

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, hover, navbar

I'm working on my first website (I'm a n00b) and on Safari and Chrome it looks exactly the way I want. However, in IE 8 the nav bar does not work at all. In Firefox, once you hover over one of the links it brings the drop down box down but it adds an extra pixel in between the main nav bar and the sub links.

My website's URL is:  http://tonerleague.x10.mx/basketball.html

My HTML is...:

```
<div class="menu">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TestTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TestTestTest</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Unknown</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

My CSS is..:

```
.menu
{
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 137px;
margin-left:-500px;
font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: .875em;
font-weight: bold;
}
    nav ul {
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0px; 
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block; 
    }
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

    nav ul ul {
display: none;
    }

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
    nav ul li {
float: left;
line-height: normal;
-moz-border-radius: 0;  
    }
nav ul li:hover {
    /*background:#C0C0C0; ** Firefox causes another extra pixel when activated*/
    line-height: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;  

}
    nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #FFF;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 5px 35px;
    color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 0px solid #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;  
}
nav ul ul {
background-color: #C0C0C0; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
line-height: normal;
-moz-border-radius: 0;  
    }
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 0px solid #FFF; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
    border-right: 0px solid #000;
    border-left: 0px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    line-height: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;  
}
    nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #000000;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT boxes are not typical HTML elements. They're closely tied to the OS and can be difficult to style, especially on IE8.

You may opt to wrap the SELECT in a DIV and set the overflow to contain the element, or use an IE8-speficic CSS declaration to tweak the size.

See: [How does one target IE7 and IE8 with valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814219/how-does-one-target-ie7-and-ie8-with-valid-css)

```
Use "\9" to target IE8 and below.
Use "*" to target IE7 and below.
Use "_" to target IE6.

Example:

body { 
border:1px solid red; /* standard */
border:1px solid blue\9; /* IE8 and below */
*border:1px solid orange; /* IE7 and below */
_border:1px solid blue; /* IE6 */
}
```

Comment: Alright, that should help with the IE problems, however, any idea of why Firefox is causing the extra pixel under the main nav when you hover?

Comment: All I can suggest is putting all styling on the A-tag, with display:block and removing it from the LI (except for position/float).

Comment: I figured it out and I feel pretty silly. I had never set a specific height on each box. Safari and Chrome set them automatically to 16px and Firefox and IE set them to 17px. Once I set a definite height it was perfect. Thanks for the IE specific code.