# Which modernizr test(s) will target IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I am trying to set up some css selectors, and I need to set up several that I want to be ignored in IE8 (actually any IE < IE9, but that's ok).

Which selector can I safely use knowing that all browsers (including IE9) support the selector but IE8 fails?

In other words, I am looking to do something like

```
.someselectorthatfailsinie .mystyle { stuff for new browsers }
```

EDIT: What I am trying to do with CSS is target and style checkboxes and radio buttons.  While IE8 supports SOME of this treatment -- the custom box -- it does not support the `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before` necessary for the pseudo checkboxes to work.

Therefore I wanted to "hide" the entire css effort from IE8, and let it show the default unstyled checkboxes.

Comment: IE8 will already ignore styles it doesn't support. And, if the `stuff for new browsers` is using particular features, why not select by those?

Comment: Depending on your specific problem, you might find this article useful: http://www.impressivewebs.com/browser-support-css3-selectors/

Comment: If you really want to style by version, "[*Explicitly Target IE versions without hacks using HTML and CSS*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4349295)."

Comment: See my edits above as to why I am doing this.

Answer (score 6):

There's so many things that ie doesn't handle, I generally do this:

.no-boxshadow .classname {border:1px solid #ddd}

Go to http://caniuse.com/ to see what IE 8 doesn't handle.

The problem with VenomVendor's answer is that .noie .mystyle is relying on javascript to be enabled to use it for the majority of browsers, which are modern. That's a lot of work. Just design your site for modern browsers then use feature detection to address older browsers.

It would be better to add a conditional statement and just target ie8 or ie9, my html looks like this, based on Boilerplate and avoids putting IE in compatibility mode. IE10 and above doesn't recognize conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE ]><![endif]-->
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="no-js lt-ie10 ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Then if I want to get ie8, I can do this:

```
.ie8 .class {styles for ie8}
```

or IE 8 and under

```
.lt-ie9 .class {styles for less than ie 9}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `noie` class for browsers higher than IE8 & other broswers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><html lang="en" class="no-js dumbie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="no-js noie" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

.noie .mystyle { stuff for new browsers }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, IE8 does not support the `canvas` element.  Modernizr will add the `canvas` class to the `<html>` tag for modern browsers, and alternatively, it will add the `no-canvas` class for IE8 and below.  Therefore, you could do this to target modern browsers:

```
.canvas .my-checkbox-style { /* CSS for modern browsers, but not IE8 or lower */ }
```

Alternatively, you could do this to target IE8 and lower:

```
.no-canvas .my-checkbox-style { /* CSS for IE8 or lower */ }
```

However, there are a couple of things worth further mention here...

Browsers will not honor CSS selectors and properties they do not support.

If the intention is to truly *hide* your modern browser CSS from IE8 entirely, you need to serve up separate stylesheets altogether via conditional statements, like this:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if gt IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-up.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="non-ie-browsers.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Architecturally speaking, presuming modern browsers are the 'first class citizens' in your styling objectives, your stylesheets should be written from their modern perspective as a norm.  This will make your overall development process easier, as well as uncluttered with classes that unnecessarily target 'modern' browsers.  Target IE8 and below with the `no-canvas` class, and over-ride the modern browser CSS therein, to return the IE8 checkboxes to their default state.  You can then easily prune this self-contained over-ride from your CSS codebase when the time comes to drop IE8 support.

I've written a [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/mbwJF) to illustrate the use of `canvas` and `no-canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that **ES5 array methods** work for detecting IE8 and lower. I happened to use the forEach in my code.
http://caniuse.com/#search=ECMAScript%205

Using **Modernizr** you can check `.no-es5array` or `.es5array` in CSS and `Modernizr.es5array` in JS.
https://modernizr.com/download?es5array-dontmin-setclasses&q=es5array