# fake onclick event in Old browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I need to create a hidden input[type=file] field and a `button` element. When you click the button an event is delegated to the file input so that a file dialog box opens. In modern brosers that is not a problem.

```
document.getElementById('readFile').onclick = function(){
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            event.initMouseEvent("click", false, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            filesInput.dispatchEvent(event) ;
}
```

or simply `filesInput.click()`
where filesInput is reference to the input[type=file] and #readFile is a button .

However for some reason this does not work in Firefox 3.6 and my spec require browser support Firefox>=3.6 
Is there any way to fake a mouse click event in Firefox 3.6 or will I just have to show that ugly default input?

I am not using JQuery or any other framework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest solution to what you're trying to do is this:

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842275/1256925), I explain how to do it the easiest way:

**HTML:**

```
<label>
    <input type="file">
    My Label
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
label input[type="file"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/run4s/1/).

That's the simplest solution, and it works even in the older browsers. Please see [my full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842275/1256925) for extra information and further explanation of why this works best.

Now, that won't work in Firefox 3.6, so for FF3.6, you could use a fallback mechanism, which would be based on [these CSS tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20982264/1256925):

**Additional CSS:**

```
label input[type="file"], body:-moz-any-link  {
    position: static;
}
:-moz-any(html) label input[type="file"] {
    position: fixed;
}
```

That way, you will first change the input's position back to `static` for all Firefox browsers, but then for the versions that support `:-moz-any()` (FF4+), you change it back again to `fixed`. That way, you will have a functional label for your file input, with a fallback for versions 1-4.

Comment: @Dharman I've added some extra info to the answer. It's not a perfect solution, but it is much simpler for all modern browsers, and it just uses a fallback mechanism for the unsupportive FF versions. Anyway, you could also drop support for FF3.6, since [it is used less than IE6 is](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php). Supporting outdated browsers is usually a huge hassle, and when browser usage gets below 0.5%, it's almost never worth it.

Comment: I don't understant that piece of CSS but the fallback works. I guess you are right, I won't worry too much about FF3.6. It is full of bugs anyway.