# Display Problems IE9 & Google Search Appliance

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-search-appliance

When using IE9 or below with our Google Search Appliance, the content does not display properly. It is so bad, that the site is unusable. It looks like the css is not being applied. If I use FF or Chrome, or IE 10 and above, all looks and works fine. Below is a link to the test site, you can replicate the problem by performing a search using the box in the right hand corner.

http://lib-wind.mohawkcollege.ca/library-testing/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to put specific CSS style for IE version below 10
Check this solution:
[How does one target IE7 and IE8 with valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814219/how-does-one-target-ie7-and-ie8-with-valid-css)

On other side, I do recommend that you loose the black-to-white gradient in the header, use #990033 for bg colour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but it did not work. The CSS is not being applied due to a Doc Type issue, specifically Quirks Mode vs Standards Mode. Read here: https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/. While in IE in developer mode, if I change the document mode from Quirks to IE9 Standards, the style sheet is applied and almost looks like it should minus a couple of small issues. What I can't figure out now though is where to add the doc type line to the XSLT style sheet. I know it should be at the very beginning of the style sheet but that does not seem to work.